# Linux - Local account, password from AD

Tags: linux, users, authentication, active-directory

I have  users defined in AD but because of some overrides, I have to add those accounts in my local /etc/passwd. Precisely, I want to assign a user a different GID then it is defined in AD.

I want to login with local user ( from /etc/passwd ) and with the use of the password from AD. When there is only local user defined and no password in /etc/shadow it doesn't work.

When I define the password locally with `passwd username` and it gets stored to /etc/shadow i can log in. If I try and remove the local user from /etc/passwd then I can login but without those overrides which I want to have.

I have tried adjusting the nsswitch.conf order and pam common-auth ( plus as suggested  [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1311099/use-ldap-server-credentials-and-local-user#answer-1313150)) but nothing worked.

Has anyone any idea how to achieve this?
LOCAL USER with AD PASSWORD
Distro: Ubuntu

Comment: not directly related, you can add to AD user a secondary group by editing `/etc/group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the solution!

One need to create the /etc/shadow entry with `passwd user` and then later manually change the password hash to *

```
If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will
       not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).
```

/etc/passwd:

```
user:*:226860:45253:test.user:/home/user:/usr/bin/bash
```

/etc/shadow

```
user:*:19198::::::
```

Important part here is **the user may log in the system by other means** - so I tried it and it works!